# Commutator element in permutation group

Tags: group-theory

Øystein Ore in 'Some remarks on commutators' proof that:

''any element of the alternating group $A_n$ with n ≥ 5 is a commutator of two elements''.

I quest the case $n=4$. I reasoned that:

1) $A_4$ is costituited from identity $1$, 3 permutation of type $(i,j)(h,k)$ [i,j,h,k distinct] and 8 of type $(i,j,h)$.

2) $[(i,j),(i,k)]=(i,k,j)$.

3) $[(i,j,k),(i,k,l)]=(i,l)(j,k)$.

Therefore ''any element of the alternating group $A_4$  is a commutator of two elements''.
Is correct?

Futhermore the cases $n=2,3$ appear obvious.
Therefore:

''any element of the alternating group $A_n$ with n ≥ 2 is a commutator of two elements''.

I ask a confirm, please.

Comment: What about $n=3$, and are you trying to prove the assertion for all $n$, given you proved it for $n \leq 4$? Please provide a link to the quoted paper. And after _therefore_ you mean probably for $n \geq 1$. For the rest everything is okay.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2775.pdf       (in introduction)

Comment: The question is very unclear. Two elements of what?

Comment: I resolved: Ore has proof that in a finite non abelian simple group every element is a commutator. This is case of $A_n$ for $n\ge 5$. For $n=4$ elements have found in $S_4$ and not in $A_4$.